# Memory consumption grows

Tags: python, django, transactions

I've written a function to import some data from csv file to DB. But when I invoke it, I can see that memory consumption grows pretty fast and importing slows down because of swap usage.

Here's the code:

```
import re
import csv

from django.db import transaction
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")

from videos.models import *

from django.db import IntegrityError

MAX_RECORDS_BULK = 500

def save_records(info_list, offset):
    i = offset * MAX_RECORDS_BULK
    with transaction.atomic():
        for info in info_list:
            try:
                with transaction.atomic():
                    try:
                        with transaction.atomic():
                            video = Video(
                                original_title=info['title'],
                                duration=info['duration'],
                                embed=info['embed']
                            )
                            video.save()
                    # Video already exists
                    except (IntegrityError, ValueError):
                        print "Video already exists"
                        continue
                    for image_url in info['images']:
                        screenshot = Screenshot(url=image_url, video=video)
                        screenshot.save()
                    for tag_title in info['tags']:
                        try:
                            with transaction.atomic():
                                tag = Tag.objects.get(title=tag_title)
                        except Tag.DoesNotExist:
                            try:
                                with transaction.atomic():
                                    tag = Tag(title=tag_title, slug=slugify(tag_title))
                                    tag.save()
                            except IntegrityError:
                                print "Couldn't create new tag"
                                continue
                        video.tags.add(tag)
                    video.save()
                    i += 1
                    print "Added record %d" % i
            except:
                continue


def csv_import(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as csv_file:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='|')
        info_list = []
        offset = 0
        for row in reader:
            info = {}

            info['title'] = row[3]
            info['embed'] = re.search('(?<=embed/)\w+', row[0]).group(0)
            info['images'] = []
            info['images'].append(row[1])
            info['images'].extend(row[2].split(';'))
            info['tags'] = []
            info['tags'].extend(row[4].split(';'))
            info['duration'] = row[7]

            info_list.append(info)

            if len(info_list) >= MAX_RECORDS_BULK:
                save_records(info_list, offset)
                info_list = []
                offset += 1
        save_records(info_list, offset)
```

I guess I don't understand how garbage collection works in python but maybe there's another issue. It also would be great if you could suggest me how I can trace the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have DEBUG=False?

Comment: You should try that, then.

Comment: why should I do that? How can it help me?

Comment: Because it'll probably solve your problem: see the [Django database FAQ](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/faq/models/#why-is-django-leaking-memory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to DanielRoseman, I just needed to set `DEBUG=False`.
Here's what Django documentation says about it:

> It is also important to remember that when running with DEBUG turned
>   on, Django will remember every SQL query it executes. This is useful
>   when you’re debugging, but it’ll rapidly consume memory on a
>   production server.